# Subquery returns multiple rows issue

Tags: mysql

Once again a question about mysql with my small database to practise with:

I got the tables as followed:

```
Songs       Link        Tags
=======     =====       =======
Sid          Sid        Tid
Songname     Tid        Tagname
```

Now what I am trying to do is once i query (or search for) a song with entering some tags, to display how many tags that song has to create a match percentage.

Thanks to the awesome stackoverflow community i got the query

```
SELECT s.Sid, s.Songname
FROM Songs s
JOIN Link l ON ( l.Sid = s.Sid )
JOIN Tags t ON ( t.Tid = s.Tid )
WHERE t.Tagname IN ( 'X', 'Y' )
GROUP BY s.Sid, s.Songname
HAVING COUNT(1) = 2
```

Which searches for songs that match exactly these 2 tags. 
Suppose now you've got this song A which has tag G, X, Y, and Z. 
The query finds this song because it has X and Y in it.
However the song got 2 others, thus I want to create (with php) a match % showing 50% for this one.
I don't have any trouble with the php part, but i cant figure out a query to get all songs that match these tags along with their total amount of tags in one result set.

Cheers!

### Edit1:

---

I noticed that most of the answers show what I've already tried. So i'll make another more deep example: 
Suppose you've got the following 4 songs: 
A with tags A, B, X and Y 
B with  tags A, B, C, D, E, X, Y 
C with tags A, B, C, D, F, X 
D with tags X and Y

Now the query for searching songs with tags X and Y is enterred. I want the following output:

```
TotalNumberOfTags:    Song:
4                      A
7                      B
2                      D
```

C didn't have X AND Y so he falls out.

### Edit2:

---

To illustrate i want to use the query

```
SELECT COUNT(t.Tagname) FROM FROM Songs s 
JOIN Link l ON ( l.Sid = s.Sid ) 
JOIN Tags t ON ( t.Tid = s.Tid ) 
WHERE s.Songname="A"
```

on the whole returning set of songnames caused by the queries above, in one query to use ORDER BY COUNT(t.Tagname) ASC on the set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer i found is a work around but it works.
I create a temporary table like this

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE numberoftags ( songname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, numberoftags INT);
```

which i fill with the 2 separate queries i displayed in my question.
Then with with a simple query

```
SELECT * FROM numberoftags ORDER BY numberoftags DESC
```

I receive all songs with their total number of tags, which i display one by one.
After i close the connection in php this temporary table automatically get's removed, so no hassling about that.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can also get the count by counting the number of records in each group (i.e. for each song) using something like...

```
SELECT s.Sid, s.Songname, COUNT(t.Tagname)
FROM Songs s
JOIN Link l ON ( l.Sid = s.Sid )
JOIN Tags t ON ( t.Tid = s.Tid ) AND t.Tagname IN ( 'X', 'Y' )
GROUP BY s.Sid, s.Songname;
```

Also, it might be easier to send a single string with the tagnames and then use Find_In_Set

```
SELECT s.Sid, s.Songname, COUNT(t.Tagname)
FROM Songs s
JOIN Link l ON ( l.Sid = s.Sid )
JOIN Tags t ON ( t.Tid = s.Tid ) AND FIND_IN_SET(t.Tagname,"G,X,Y,Z")>0
GROUP BY s.Sid, s.Songname;
```

I obviously did not understand as I thought that the list of tagnames used in the search was the dynamic element.   I believe that you can use an inner query to get the songs that match your search criteria (e.g. "X","Y") and then use an outer query on the songs to get each one's tag count

```
select COUNT(to.Tagname), so.Songname FROM FROM Songs so 
JOIN Link lo ON ( lo.Sid = so.Sid ) 
JOIN Tags to ON ( to.Tid = so.Tid ) 
WHERE so.SongName in
   ( SELECT si.SongName
      FROM Songs si
      JOIN Link li ON ( li.Sid = si.Sid )
      JOIN Tags ti ON ( ti.Tid = si.Tid )
      WHERE ti.Tagname IN ( 'X', 'Y' )
      GROUP BY si.Sid, si.Songname
      HAVING COUNT(1) = 2
   )
order by COUNT(to.Tagname);
```

Comment: the problem is that this count counts the enterred amount of tags, rather than find out how many tags each song has.

Comment: I obviously did not understand as I thought that the list of tagnames used in the search was the dynamic element.   I believe that you can use an inner query to get the songs that match your search criteria (e.g. "X","Y") and then use an outer query on the songs to get each one's tag count:

Comment: That results in an error: subquery returned multiple rows. But i found a work around. THanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Remove the HAVING clause - don't think it is needed.  Add `COUNT(l.Sid) AS MatchedTags` in the SELECT statement.

```
SELECT s.Sid, s.Songname, COUNT(l.Sid) AS MatchedTags
FROM Songs s
JOIN Link l ON ( l.Sid = s.Sid )
JOIN Tags t ON ( t.Tid = s.Tid )
WHERE t.Tagname IN ( 'X', 'Y' )
GROUP BY s.Sid, s.Songname
HAVING COUNT(1) = 2
```

Also - it's down to personal opinion but as a general rule I name the "link" tables in a many to many relationship as a combination of the 2 table names that are involved.  For example you would have Song, Tag, and the middle table SongTag.

And always avoid acronyms where possible!  The primary key column in each table can just be called Id, and the SongTag table (Or Link table) would have SongId, and TagId rather than sid and tid.

If the `HAVING COUNT(1) = 2` is needed, change the (1) to actually refer to the column name for ease of reading.

Bad habits but again it is only my personal opinion.

My query ended up looking like this:  (with 2 songs and 5 tags).

```
SELECT 
    s.Id, 
    s.Name,
    COUNT(st.Id) AS MatchedTags
FROM 
    SongTag st
        INNER JOIN Song s ON st.SongId = s.Id
        INNER JOIN Tag t ON st.TagId = t.Id
WHERE 
    t.Name IN ('Tag2', 'Tag3', 'Tag4', 'Tag5')
GROUP BY
    s.Id,
    s.Name
```

Comment: THe having clause was the key element to hit songs that had x AND Y in them, removing it gives also songs which has either X or Y. I'll try your suggestion and will comment if it worked or not.

Comment: Nope this didn't work, it shows the amount of tags enterred. e.g. i enterred 2 tags and the result of all songs was that the count was 2, whereas some songs actually have 5 tags assigned to them.

Comment: But you only wanted matched tags right?  Not sure what the point of showing the total count of all the tags for that song is...?  Isn't (X or Y) better than (X and Y)?  You can then ORDER BY MatchedTags DESC to get the best hits - that way when several tags are entered 1 bad tag wont prevent results from being returned.

Comment: That's one of my queryies i managed to achieve, but i also want to show how much of those tags that are enterred match the song in total. So with the addional example those 3 songs popped up matching BOTH tags, now i want to create a view showing the best percentage of actually the 'best match'.

So with the example we get 2/4 × 100% = 50% for A - 2/7 = 17% somewhat for B and last 2/2 which is a 100% match for C Thus i want to show C first, then A and then B in the list of matches.